# How do I put a <label> over a textbox control in ASP.Net using CSS?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to create one row with some text boxes with label's over them like this:

[image]

How do I align the labels up with the text boxes?

```
        <label>Student ID</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStudentID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <label>Student Last Name</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStuLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <label>Student First Name</label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtStuFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Here's my current CSS.

```
.boxround label {
    display: block;        
    float: left;
}
```

This is what I current get:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be better if you enclosed each group inside a div.

For example:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Student ID</label>
   <asp:TextBox ID="txtStudentID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

And apply the following CSS for class 'form-group':

```css
.form-group{
   display: inline-block;
   margin-right: 10px;
   float:left;
}

.form-group label{
   display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Student ID</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Student ID</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Student ID</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could also make use of display: flex-box (there's a comprehensive guide [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)).

Hope that helped!

Answer (score 0):

Put the input tag inside the `label` tag (and add a line break `<br>`):

```
    <label>Student ID<br><asp:TextBox ID="txtStudentID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></label>
    <label>Student Last Name<br><asp:TextBox ID="txtStuLastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></label>
    <label>Student First Name<br><asp:TextBox ID="txtStuFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></label>
```